# Bash sort -nu results in unexpected behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, command

A colleague of mine noticed some odd behaviour with the sort command today, and I was wondering if anyone knows if the output of this command is intentional or not?

Given the file:

```
ABC_22
ABC_43
ABC_1
ABC_1
ABC_43
ABC_10
ABC_123
```

We are looking to sort the file with numeric sort, and also make it unique, so we run:

```
sort file.txt -nu
```

The output is:

```
ABC_22
```

Now, we know that the numeric sort won't work in this case as the lines don't begin with numbers (and that's fine, this is just part of a larger script), but I would have expected something more along the lines of:

```
ABC_1
ABC_10
ABC_123
ABC_22
ABC_43
```

Does anyone know why this isn't the case? The sort acts as one would expect if given just the -u or -n options individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing specifying the de-limit on the second field of `GNU sort` as

```
sort -nu -t'_' -k2 file
ABC_1
ABC_10
ABC_22
ABC_43
ABC_123
```

The flag `-n` for numerical sort, `-u` for unique lines and the *key* part is to set de-limiter as `_` and sort on the second field after `_` done by `-k2`.

Answer (score 2):

With `-n`, [an empty number is zero](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html):

> Sort numerically. The number begins each line and consists of optional
>   blanks, an optional ‘-’ sign, and zero or more digits possibly
>   separated by thousands separators, optionally followed by a
>   decimal-point character and zero or more digits. An empty number is
>   treated as ‘0’.

All these lines have an empty number at the start of the line, so they are all zero for `sort`'s numerical uniqueness. If you'd started each line with the same number, say `1`, the effect would be the same. You should specify the field containing the numbers explicitly, or use version sort (`-V`):

```
$ sort -Vu foo
ABC_1
ABC_10
ABC_22
ABC_43
ABC_123
```